# Migration from C2DM to GCM

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html), but I don't understand what I must do. Now my application doing registration in c2dm by this code:

```
String pushId =  C2DMessaging.getRegistrationId(this);
if(pushId == "")
{
    C2DMessaging.register(this, "email@gmail.com");
}
```

What I must change in this code to do migration from c2dm to gcm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go through the [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) steps. Once you created an API project, you will receive a 'Project ID', as mentioned #4 item on that document:

```
Take note of the value after #project: (4815162342 in this example). This is your project ID, and it will be used later on as the GCM sender ID.
```

So you just need to change your code to:

```
C2DMessaging.register(this, "4815162342");
```

The senderID must be a string number.

I am using the example from the 'Getting Started' guide, you should replace the sender ID with your own Project ID.

Finally, go through the [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html), as you need to make some changes to the server for all of these to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to change is basically the email address.
You need to send instead the API Key which you received in Google APIs Console page.

Answer (score 0):

In GCM to get rid from Qutota google removed the signup an activation of an email for using Google Cloud Service.

When you go to [Google Developer Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) Here and click on create a new project that will give you a new **project id** that will be present in URL.

The **PROJECT ID** here will work like a **user name** and one more thing, this time Google is providing a jar **gcm.jar** that you need to add in your project classpath using build path to make GCM work .

this jar contains a class named GCMRegistrar having predefined function register() so you just need to add this code and forget

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

> In C2DM **SENDER_ID** : Activated **Gmail ID**.
>
> In GCM  **SENDER_ID**  : **PROJECT ID** in url .