# C2DM to GCM android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I follow this tutorial doing my App, now I need migrate c2dm to GCM anybody made this before?

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration from C2DM to GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326065/migration-from-c2dm-to-gcm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate [parse](https://parse.com/) in your application.
[Androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/) also has nice tutorial, how to use parse.